# Find multiple files in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, search

I am searching for files in linux and am able to execute the command to search for a single type of format e.g `*.jpg` but would like to find all files with `*.jpg` and `*.css` in one command.

Comment: Next time you should try to read `man YOURCOMMAND` (in this case `find`) first.

Comment: @PaulR: If you don't use regexexs, maybe, but both, find and locate, can handle regex, and therefore it can be alright here, imho.

Answer (score 10):

```
 find -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.css"
```

Comment: This `./` seems a bit unnecessary here?

Answer (score 5):

There is a fingerbreaking variant with regex:

```
find -regex ".*\.\(css\|jpg\)"
```

It's shorter and avoid pitfalls, combined with the -o versions:

```
find ./ -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.css" -ls
```

The ls is only adapted to the second pattern, here. You can avoid it with

```
find ./ \( -name "*.jpg" -o -name "*.css" \) -ls
```

but that is getting a bit cryptic too.

Very fast for searching your whole system in the update-db-index is locate, which knows regex too, but doesn't find ultra fresh files:

```
locate -r "Frame.\(scal\|jav\)a"
```

Comment: Test it! In my machine the option without the brackets does not work - no errors are reported, but still only the last file pattern is applied.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can type :

```
find -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.css"
```